# Windows 7 Installer keeps popping up at startup

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, installer, popups

I have Solidworks Student Edition installed on an external drive. Every time I turn on my computer, a Windows Installer box pops up to install Solidworks, and I have to press Cancel. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Repair the installation of Solidworks.  The reason your getting that prompt is likely because of the installation location and Windows Installer thinks its missing something that is required.

Comment: also, check msconfig. like @Ramhound said the installer could be busted, but if the program is set to run at startup, then it may be trying to reinstall itself during startup. This may be confirmed by trying to directly run the program from the start menu or wherever.

Comment: Also check your external drive for any autorun.ini files that are attempting to autorun the application.

Answer (score 0):

Go to run and type msconfig and then in the dialog go to startup and disable the one causing problems.

Answer (score -1):

How do I stop Windows Installer from popping up?

My solution:
Find file: hpqtra08.exe. Remove it to the desktop, 
don't delete it. The pop up's stopped for me.

ThePast